# Database Helper returns -1

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I m trying to create a simple data saving app with SQLite,but i can't seem to run in properly.My DB object **returns -1** and the insertion fails as all the other functions.A little help please!Below is my Code:

Main Activity:

```
package com.example.sql_indos;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    EditText name,contact,dob;
    Button insert,update,delete,view;
    DBHelper DB;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        //ΕDITTEXT
        name = findViewById(R.id.idname);
        contact = findViewById(R.id.idcontact);
        dob = findViewById(R.id.iddate);

        //BUTTONS
        insert = findViewById(R.id.idinsert);
        delete = findViewById(R.id.iddelete);
        update = findViewById(R.id.idupdate);
        view = findViewById(R.id.idview);

        DB = new DBHelper(this);



        //INSERT
        insert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String nameTXT =  name.getText().toString();
                String contactTXT = contact.getText().toString();
                String dobTXT = dob.getText().toString();


                Boolean checkinsertdata = DB.insertuserdata(nameTXT,contactTXT,dobTXT);//EDW

                if(checkinsertdata == true)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }








            }
        });



        //UPDATE
        update.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String nameTXT =  name.getText().toString();
                String contactTXT = contact.getText().toString();
                String dobTXT = dob.getText().toString();


                Boolean checkupdatedata = DB.updateuserdata(nameTXT,contactTXT,dobTXT);

                if(checkupdatedata == true)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        });

        //DELETE
        delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String nameTXT =  name.getText().toString();


                Boolean checkdeletedata = DB.deletedata(nameTXT);

                if(checkdeletedata == true)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        });


        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Cursor res = DB.getdata();
                if(res.getCount() == 0)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No entry happened", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;


                }
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                while(res.moveToNext())
                {
                    buffer.append("Name :" + res.getString(0)+"\n");
                    buffer.append("Contact :" + res.getString(1)+"\n");
                    buffer.append("Date of Birth :" + res.getString(2)+"\n\n");


                }

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                builder.setCancelable(true);
                builder.setTitle("User entries");
                builder.setMessage(buffer.toString());
                builder.show();




            }
        });



    }
}
```

DB Helper:

```
package com.example.sql_indos;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, "Userdata.db", null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase DB) {

        DB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE Userdetails(name TEXT PRIMARY KEY, contact TEXT, dob TEXT)");


    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase DB, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        DB.execSQL("drop Table if exists Userdetails");

    }


    //INSERT
    public Boolean insertuserdata(String name, String contact, String dob) {


        SQLiteDatabase DB = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

        contentValues.put("Name", name);
        contentValues.put("Contact", contact);
        contentValues.put("Date of Birth", dob);


        long result = DB.insert("Userdetails", null, contentValues);//EDW

        if (result == -1) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }

    }


    //UPDATE
    public Boolean updateuserdata(String name, String contact, String dob) {


        SQLiteDatabase DB = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

        contentValues.put("Name", name);
        contentValues.put("Contact", contact);
        contentValues.put("Date of Birth", dob);
        Cursor cursor = DB.rawQuery("select * from Userdetails where name = ?", new String[]{name});
        if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {


            long result = DB.update("Userdetails", null, "name=?", new String[]{name});

            if (result == -1) {
                return false;
            }else {
                return true;
            }


        }else {


            return false;
        }


    }


    //DELETE
    public Boolean deletedata(String name) {


        SQLiteDatabase DB = this.getWritableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = DB.rawQuery("select * from Userdetails where name = ?", new String[]{name});
        if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {

            long result = DB.delete("Userdetails", "name=?", new String[]{name});


            if (result == -1) {
                return false;
            }else {
                return true;
            }


        }else {


            return false;
        }


    }

    ///edw


    //DISPLAY
    public Cursor getdata() {


        SQLiteDatabase DB = this.getWritableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = DB.rawQuery("select * from Userdetails ", null);

        return cursor;


    }








}
```

```
at com.example.sql_indos.DBHelper.insertuserdata(DBHelper.java:46)
 at com.example.sql_indos.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:52)
```

I Want to clarify that the app **does NOT Crash**,it runs but it fails to execute any useful functions.So it must be a logical mistake or something is outdated and i 'm not aware about it!Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> contentValues.put("Date of Birth", dob);
> ```

You don't have a column named `Date of Birth` but you do have one named `dob`. Change it to `dob` here.

For easier debugging, consider using `insertOrThrow()` in place of `insert()` so you get helpful exceptions.

Comment: Life saver!Thank you so much!